# Transform content type to query view into database

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I have retrieved the content type Student from my database in my module with PHP. How can I save this content type, like a view, and store it into my database? I use drupal 6.

Comment: A view and a content type are two different things; a view is a view over a list of nodes, or users, or taxonomy terms. When you save a view, you save the settings for that view, such us which content type must be show, if the nodes shown in the view are promoted in front page, which user is the author of those nodes, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get content type with PHP from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472783/get-content-type-with-php-from-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export and import content types using Content Copy module (included in CCK package). If you want to display the list of nodes of content type Student, you need to create a new View, where you can set up the filter to show nodes of "Student" type only.